# How do I use the prepend function in jQuery to make my code more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write `javascript` code that will emulate a program that prints ping for numbers divisible by three, pong for numbers divisible by five, and ping-pong for numbers divisible by both, otherwise just printing the number. I've got it to work but I know I should probably use `jQuery` to make this more efficient. I been following a tutorial on the prepend method and read up on it a bit but I can't figure out how to implement it into my code yet. Any pointers?

```
<ul>
     <script>
     ppCount = prompt("What number would you like me to ping-pong up to?");
     // document.write(console.log(ppCount));
     function pingPong (ppCount) {
          for (var index = 1; index <= ppCount; index += 1) {
               if (index % 3 === 0 && index % 5 === 0) {
                    document.write('<li>' + "ping-pong" + '</li>')
               } else if (index % 3 === 0) {
                    document.write('<li>' + "ping" + '</li>')
                } else if (index % 5 === 0) {
                    document.write('<li>' + "pong" + '</li>')
                } else {
                    document.write('<li>' + index +'</li>')
                }
                document.write('<br>')
            }
        };
        pingPong(ppCount);
    </script>
</ul>
```

Comment: FYI, since jQuery adds an additional layer of abstraction on top of DOM, it's usually *less* efficient in terms of runtime behavior. However, you'd hardly notice the difference anyway. *"but I can't figure out how to implement it into my code yet"* Well, where are you stuck? We could point you back to the documentation, but since you are already looking at it, you have to be a bit more specific about your actual problem.

Comment: `// document.write(console.log(ppCount));` <-- what were you trying to achieve with that? You don't need to wrap a console.log in a document.write.

Comment: $('body').prepend('<li>' + "ping-pong" + '</li>'); should work but depends on what you're trying to prepend to. But as mentioned above, doesn't mean it's more efficent.

Comment: @BjornTipling, that was left over from earlier when the code was spitting out weird values, I had that and another console.log in there to see what the value of the variable ppCount was at those respective points - thanks for pointing that out need to remove it from the code. I guess it isn't more efficient to use jQuery in this case.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, You are writing the contents of document - on the fly - while the document is being loaded.

i.e, `document.write()` writes the content where it is encountered (*In this case, inside the `<ul>`*). I'm afraid it's possible to do the same with jQuery...

---

If you want to do this after the `<ul>` is created, You can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var ppCount = new Array(prompt("What number would you like me to ping-pong up to?"));
   function pingPong(ppCount) {
    for (var index = 1; index <= ppCount; index++) {
      if (index % 3 === 0 && index % 5 === 0) {
        $("ul").append('<li>ping-pong</li>')
      } else if (index % 3 === 0) {
        $("ul").append('<li>ping</li>')
      } else if (index % 5 === 0) {
        $("ul").append('<li>pong</li>')
      } else {
        $("ul").append('<li>' + index + '</li>')
      }
    }
  };
  pingPong(ppCount);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5kj1m493/

```
<ul></ul>
```

and

```
$(function() {
 $.each(new Array(prompt("What number would you like me to ping-pong up to?") * 1),
    function(ind) {
       var i = ind + 1;
       var message = !(i % 5) && !(i % 3) ? 'ping-pong' : 
       (!(i % 5) ? 'pong' : (!(i % 3) ? 'ping' : i));
       $('<li>').html(message).appendTo($('ul'));        
  });
});
```

Or with `for` loop ))